# BASH - curl -L not working

Tags: curl

with -L flash , curl should follow redirection but i have 301 Moved permanently .

For e.g : curl -I -L -s era-min-eu.org | head -n 1

Response : HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are head-ing the output and only showing the first line in your example code. Running that command without head shows the rest of the response:

```
$ curl -I -L -s era-min-eu.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Location: http://era-min.prod.lamp.cnrs.fr
Cache-Control: max-age=10800

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:36 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:36 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: ee178549c4135355897a0fd336ea26d8=0jabfedtnk08u4ru0u29uq9a86; path=/; HttpOnly
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

As @zzevann explained above, the redirect does work. The initial site gives the 301 error, but below it forwards and displays the curl info for the updated site indicated in the `Location: http://era-min.prod.lamp.cnrs.fr` line.

Run curl on the updated URL:

```
$ curl -I -L -s era-min.prod.lamp.cnrs.fr
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 16:27:28 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 16:27:28 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: ee178549c4135355897a0fd336ea26d8=iccsu7vp1f99qvhgcbvbk8t102; path=/; HttpOnly
Connection: close
```